# Listener from adapter to activitiy thru long chain of elements

Tags: java, android, rx-java, event-bus

I have a chain of elements like this:

```
Activity --> FragmentPagerAdapter --> Fragment --> RecyclerView.Adapter
```

I need the listener (interface?) to listen to activities of RecyclerView.Adapter in Activity. I can implement many interfaces between elements but it doesn't make sense, right?

As far as I understand, it's necessary to use Observers (EventBus). There are deprecated frameworks like `EventBus` and `Otto`. Nowadays, instead of that, we can use `RxJava`? I never learn it before. The time has come or there are other ways to do that, like `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: Not sure what the question is here... it seems like you know what the options are for communicating between parts of the application. Are you asking what the best option is for your scenario? Or how to use a `BroadcastReceiver` to communicate?

Comment: I would highly recommend using RxJava. I think what you are looking for is something like a `BehaviorSubject`.

Comment: @pushasha My apologies for not clearness of the question. You're right, my question is what the best option in my scenario? Even if a chain will be much deeper.